# Will a newly recruited Aztec swordsman have the special ability of the Eagle warrior?

Tags: civilization-6

Will a newly recruited Aztec swordsman have the special ability of the Eagle warrior? Should I make a huge batch early on?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is **NO**.

From [**this**](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Eagle_Warrior_(Civ6)) wiki page.

> Unfortunately, Eagle Warrior's ability is lost when it upgrades to a Swordsman.

Comment: Even upgrades? It's even worse than I thought!

Comment: @BarAkiva No, upgrades are maintained!

Comment: ^ any units Unique Ability IS lost when upgrading to a higher tier unit in Civ VI. Of course, you do not lose any promotions bonuses, exp or levels.
In previous games, upgrading a Chu-Ko-Nu (for example) into another unit still let the unit keep it's fire twice ability, which was very OP.

Comment: In Civ5, unique abilities were implemented as special promotions assigned by the game engine when training that unit.